# $watch is not called, Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, angularjs-scope

I have a problem with $scope.$watch call, when it obviously should be called. 
I have a paginator (bootstrap UI) inside my html document:

```
<pagination  total-items="paginatorTotalItems" items-per-page="paginatorItemsPerPage" 
   page="paginatorCurrentPage" max-size="paginatorSize" class="pagination-sm" 
   boundary-links="true">
</pagination>
```

A certain part, where my items are shown (for them I need a paginator):

```
<div ng-show="reviews" ng-repeat="review in reviewsPerPage">
...
</div>
```

And a Controller:

```
...
$scope.reviewsArray = [];
$scope.paginatorItemsPerPage = 1;
$scope.paginatorSize = 3;
$scope.reviewsPerPage = [];
$scope.paginatorTotalItems = $scope.reviews.result.total;

       //restangular object to Array
       for (var i = 0; i < $scope.paginatorTotalItems; i++) {
           $scope.reviewsArray.push($scope.reviews.result.reviews[i]);
       };

       $scope.paginatorCurrentPage = 1;

$scope.$watch('paginatorCurrentPage', function () {
               var begin = (($scope.paginatorCurrentPage - 1) * $scope.paginatorItemsPerPage);
               var end = begin + $scope.paginatorItemsPerPage;

               console.log($scope.paginatorCurrentPage);
               console.log(begin + ' ' + end);

               $scope.reviewsPerPage = $scope.reviewsArray.slice(begin,end);

               console.log($scope.reviewsPerPage);
});
```

So, making long story short, I have a variable paginatorCurrentPage, that I change by clicking numbers in my `<pagination>`, but $watch does not react. This $watch is called only once: when I'm assigning it a value of 1 (after making an array from my restangular object), after that $watch is never called anymore. 
Also I'm cheking how paginatorCurrentPage changes in my html file:

```
<p>Current : {{paginatorCurrentPage}}</p>
```

And it actually works, this variable is changing, when i switch my pagination buttons, but $watch is not called.

Sorry for my English, and Thank you!

**Edited :**

I have updated my bootstrap UI, so now in paginator I use `ng-model` istead of `page`. And I realized that variable paginatorCurrentPage changes only in my view, but in controller I still have my default `$scope.paginatorCurrentPage = 1`. Problem still exists.

Comment: Where is `paginatorCurrentPage` been modified? Can you show us the code that modify `paginatorCurrentPage` ?

Comment: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination <- this does not define a `page` attribute. Rather, it is using `ng-model`. Also, there is a `ng-change` event you can bind to and not need $watch at all.

Comment: @Callebe , it's modified by clicking on buttons of my pagination: page="paginatorCurrentPage".

Comment: @Malk , if I use ng-model, I have an error:
Expression 'undefined' used with directive 'pagination' is non-assignable!

Comment: Are you calling the $scope.apply inside of your directive? How have you defined your scope inside directive?

Comment: @Callebe, I haven't created any directives for it, I'm using bootstrap ui.

Comment: If you are missing the dot, you're not doing it right: https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=ZhfUv0spHCY#t=1758s

Comment: @LeoFarmer I'm not sure I understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all comments. The problem was about scope. I rewrote ng-model in paginator: `ng-model="paginatorPage.current"`

and changed

```
$scope.paginatorCurrentPage = 1;
```

to

```
$scope.paginatorPage = {current : 1};
```

And thanks to [@Leo Farmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2793265/leo-farmer) for advice about dots in directives.